# AngularJS routing noob

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing

I am trying to build my first AngularJS routing code but I can't seem to get it to work and error console isn't of much help.

My HTML page:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="AppController">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/template1">Template 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/template2">Template 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/template3">Template 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/somepage">SomePage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/default">Otherwise</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
```

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/template1', {
        templateUrl:'partials/template_1.html'
    })
    .when('/template2', {
        templateUrl:'partials/template_2.html'
    })
    .when('/template3', {
        templateUrl:'partials/template_3.html'
    })
    .when('/somepage', {
        templateUrl:'partials/somepage.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'partials/otherwise.html'
    });
});
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of angularjs are you uding? Newer verdions require routing to be loaded separately

Comment: using angular 1.2 and 1.2.5 for route

Comment: does url is changing in `url` bar?

Comment: yes, the url changes

Comment: @Kalzone  Does console is showing any errors?

Comment: I get a "TypeError: undefined is not a function" in angular.min.js

Comment: That means you are trying to access a property which is undefined.can you please upload your controller code? There must be problem inside your controller.

Comment: My controller is empty

`myApp.controller("AppController", function($scope){
 
});`

Comment: try upgrading angular to 1.2.26 which is more stable version / may be you are missing to add angular.route.js reference inside your html page.
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>` your version may be varry

Comment: @pankajparkar Thank you! Changing the version files actually worked!

Comment: @Kalzone added the answer, you can mark it as correct if it does helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your `angular.js` version to 1.2.26 which is most stabled Angular Version.
Other code looks fine to me.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks.